# Set text for table with double click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have several tables with ajax loaded content. Sometimes I have to change the content of a `td` manually before exporting it to PDF, so I thought best way would be to create a trigger for each `td` on double-click using jQuery's `.dblclick()`. The trigger would open a modal with an `input` field and change the text of the double-clicked `td` when submitting the modal.

This works, but when I change the content of a second, third, etc `td`, each previously clicked `td` gets the new value too.

Check my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fvoufq07/

My code so far:

```
$( ".sitename" ).dblclick( function() {
    var sitename = $( this );
    $( "#msgBox .modal-title" ).html("Change sitename");
    $( "#msgBox .modal-body" ).html("Enter new sitename:<input type=\"text\" id=\"new_sitename\">");
    $( "#msgBox" ).modal("show");
    $( "#msgBox button.btn" ).click( function() {
    sitename.text( $( "#new_sitename" ).val().trim() );
});

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you re-use the same button for the modal. So everytime the modal is opened, you add a new listener on the button, but you don't kill the previous one.

You can kill a previous listener with `off` :

```
$( ".sitename" ).dblclick( function() {
    var sitename = $( this );

    $( "#msgBox .modal-title" ).html("Change sitename");
    $( "#msgBox .modal-body" ).html("Enter new sitename:<input type=\"text\" id=\"new_sitename\">");
    $( "#msgBox" ).modal("show");
    $( "#msgBox button.btn" ).off('click').click( function() {
        sitename.text( $( "#new_sitename" ).val().trim() );
    });

});
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem you're seeing is that the click function you add to the button

```
$( "#msgBox button.btn" ).click( function() {
    sitename.text( $( "#new_sitename" ).val().trim() );
});
```

is not removed. Because of this, every time you open the model anew, you change the text of any previously clicked `.sitename` as well as the newly clicked one.

In order to avoid this, you should remove the click event, or better yet use jQuery's `.one()` function which will only fire the callback on the first instance of an trigger event:

```
$( "#msgBox button.btn" ).one('click', function() {
    sitename.text( $( "#new_sitename" ).val().trim() );
});
```

*Updated fiddle:* https://jsfiddle.net/fvoufq07/6/

**Update:** The above solution doesn't catch the problem of opening the modal then closing without clicking the "close" save button.

There are a couple of ways to fix this: either use `.off()` before adding the new `.one()` callback, or again use `.off()`, but conditionally upon the modal closing using bootstap's `hidden.bs.modal` trigger.

```
$( "#msgBox" ).one('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
    $( "#msgBox button.btn" ).off('click');
});
```

You might also want to assign the `'click'` listener to a variable so that you can remove that listener specifically, which will be useful if you have other `'click'` listeners on the same element.

```
var updateText = $( "#msgBox button.btn" ).one('click', function() {
    ...
});
$( "#msgBox" ).one('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
    $( "#msgBox button.btn" ).off('click', updateText);
});
```

Updated fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/fvoufq07/7/ has an example.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
var sitename;
$( ".sitename" ).dblclick( function() {
    sitename = $(this);
    $( "#msgBox .modal-title" ).html("Change sitename ");
    $( "#msgBox .modal-body" ).html("Enter new sitename:<input type=\"text\" id=\"new_sitename\">");
    $( "#msgBox" ).modal("show");
});

$( "#msgBox button.btn" ).click( function() {
        $(sitename).text( $( "#new_sitename" ).val().trim() );
    });
```

here is updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fvoufq07/5/)

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$( ".sitename" ).dblclick( function() {
sitename = $( this );
$( "#msgBox .modal-title" ).html("Change sitename");
$( "#msgBox .modal-body" ).html("Enter new sitename:<input type=\"text\" id=\"new_sitename\">");
$( "#msgBox" ).modal("show");
$( "#msgBox button.btn" ).click( function() {
    sitename.text( $( "#new_sitename" ).val().trim() );
});
```

});

Krupesh Kotecha beat me too it ;)